# Unable to start ScreenShare on opentok using opentok accelerator core js on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opentok

I'm using [THIS](https://github.com/opentok/accelerator-sample-apps-js/tree/master/vanilla-js-sample-app) opentok demo app which have features like chat, Archiving, ScreenShare and I'm stucked on Screen Share.
For screen share it needs a chrome extension and that extension I build successfully and place that ExtensionID in code so that when user clicks on screen share button then Extension will be installed. once user clicks on button then extension installs then if again click on that button to start screen share, it installs again(ScreenShare must be started if extension is installed but its not following the flow).

**may be Error is in manifest.json of extension**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in this case was the `matches` field of the chrome extension `manifest.json`.
The OP was missing a trailing `*` needed for his project.

The chrome developer docs give this example:

```
 // Match patterns for web pages. Does not affect content scripts.
// If this field is not specified, no webpages can connect.
"matches": [
  "https://*.google.com/*",
  "*://*.chromium.org/*",
  ...
],
```

See official chrome docs for more details https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable.